# Why am I getting this local variable referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, variables, keylogger

I am using this code to log keys and am trying to get it to run a function whenever 10 keys are pressed.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import time
log_dir = ""
amountofkeypressed
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
def everysec():
    if amountofkeypressed == 10:
        print("HI")
def on_press(key):

    amountofkeypressed = amountofkeypressed + 1
    everysec()
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    amountofkeypressed = 0
    listener.join()
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: what are you trying to do in line #5 ? did you mean: `amountofkeypressed = 0` ?

Comment: yes sorry it must have been cut off sorry